# REST API call in batch APEX

Tags: rest-api, batch, integration

In after insert trigger of account I need to call a rest API and have to post the data. I did this by creating a normal APEX method and doing the call out. But in some where I saw that even if we post single data then it will be good to implement the call out using Batch Apex.

Not sure which one is correct either batch  APEX or normal APEX method. Which is good approach. Any inputs please?

Comment: Always good to cite what you already found. However, since triggers can be called in a bulk manner, I recommend you use platform events to take your callout into a separate context since the number of callouts permitted per transaction is way lower than the number of records you can create or update in a transaction.

Comment: There are a few problems with triggers and REST calls to be considered carefully: 1st is the granularity, 2nd is error handling and retrying, 3rd is coupling, 4th is the performance, 5th is the external service limitations (i.e. throttling). Based on my experience you'll need to queue your items for syncing/retrying and use batch.